# Create/Update/Delete through my Code or Manual Operation in Database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, zend-framework2

How would I know when create, update and delete operations on my Database is through my written code ?? or manual operation in DB ??
sometime developer needs access to production server :(

Comment: you could just turn on the mysql query log

Answer (score 0):

In order to track history, you need to enable the "SQL history feature" of phpMyAdmin. You can find details on how to do this on the [documentation site](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/).

One thing to note is that the SQL history feature will only track commands entered via the phpMyAdmin interface. If you're looking for specific transaction history on a given table that an application does, you will need to implement some kind of tracking or log feature into the application(s) involved.

Depending on how things are setup, you may be able to access the [binary log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html) of the MySQL database itself through phpMyAdmin. You'll need to look into your current database configuration to see where/how to access it.

Comment: phpmyadmin was never mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

make sure developer is using a unique user so you can identify him

log mysql queries to table mysql.general_log

```
SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE'
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON'
```

then you can check mysql.general_log and watch for connect commands from that user (the queires he run would be right after the connect command)

hope this helps